Web Scraping with R CSS Trouble
I am trying to do web scrraping for my assignment in school but there one problem I have we are doing scraping on a cragist website and here my code
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

Davis_url <- "https://sacramento.craigslist.org/search/apa?search_distance=10&s="

scrape_page <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)
  titles <- page %>% html_nodes(".title") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  prices <- page %>% html_nodes(".price") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  
  # Handle missing square footage by checking for existence and replacing with NA
  sqfts <- page %>% html_nodes(".post-sqft") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  if (length(sqfts) == 0) {
    sqfts <- NA
  }
  
  # Handle missing bedrooms by checking for existence and replacing with NA
  bedrooms <- page %>% html_nodes(".post-bedrooms") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  if (length(bedrooms) == 0) {
    bedrooms <- NA
  }
  
  data <- data.frame(
    title = titles,
    price = prices,
    sqft = sqfts,
    bedrooms = bedrooms,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  return(data)
}

all_data <- data.frame()

for (i in seq(0, 480, by = 120)) {  
  url <- paste0(Davis_url, i)
  page_data <- scrape_page(url)
  all_data <- bind_rows(all_data, page_data)  # Append results to the data frame
  Sys.sleep(1)  # Pause for 1 second to avoid getting blocked
}

print(all_data)

however only the price title work and the sqft and bedrooms return NA
and I have try the css which it is .post-sqft but I still having trouble to return sqft now I am super confuse because I don't know what was wrong

Can't access the website

https://sacramento.craigslist.org/search/apa?search_distance=10#search=1~gallery~0~0

Some of those details are not present in page source and are pulled & rendered by javascript running in your browser, read_html() just pulls the page source and knows nothing about dynamic content. If you want to handle this trhough rvest, there's read_html_live() -- it starts headless browser though chromote and loads & renders that page as you would see in your browser & in its dev. tools. And you must slightly adjust selectors too.
This is how collecting those details for one page might look like:
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Davis_url <- "https://sacramento.craigslist.org/search/apa?search_distance=10&s=0"

sess <- read_html_live(Davis_url)
Sys.sleep(2)

# building column vectros is not ideal here as any of those ads might miss a 
# field or few, thus it's safer to iterate over <li> items and collect 
# details into list of named lists (i.e build rows instead of columns, missing
# fields are filled with NAs)
sess |>
  html_elements("li[title]") |>
  map(\(li) list(
    title = html_attr(li, "title"),
    price = html_element(li, ".priceinfo") |> html_text(),
    sqft  = html_element(li, ".post-sqft") |> html_text(),
    br    = html_element(li, ".post-bedrooms") |> html_text()
  )) |>
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 120 × 4
#>    title                                                       price sqft  br   
#>    <chr>                                                       <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 2bd 2ba, On-site Management, Parking Type: Surface Lot      $3,2… 969f… 2br  
#>  2 1x1 unit Heart of Carmichael!!!!!.                          $1,3… 650f… 1br  
#>  3 Look & Lease Same Day Receive 2 Months Rent!! Call Today!   $2,7… 1090… 1br  
#>  4 Where every corner tells a story: Discover our Studio oasi… $1,6… 549f… <NA> 
#>  5 Swimming Pool, On-Site Management, On-site Maintenance, Re… $1,2… 600f… 1br  
#>  6 Make yourself at home in our quiet 1136 sq ft 2 bed / 2 ba… $2,5… 1136… 2br  
#>  7 Unveiling a haven of style: Your perfect 1 BR awaits.       $1,6… 528f… 1br  
#>  8 Tour Today, Lighted Basketball & Tennis Courts, Dog Spa & … $2,2… 900f… 2br  
#>  9 Gas Fireplaces available, Club House and Business Center    $1,8… 790f… 1br  
#> 10 Your spacious luxury 1 Bed / 1 Bath is waiting for you! To… $1,6… 528f… 1br  
#> # ℹ 110 more rows

Created on 2024-06-06 with reprex v2.1.0
